# Execute Dynamic Select into string in Teradata

Tags: t-sql, plsql, teradata, plsqldeveloper

This is the MySQL query, now I need this below dynamic query to execute in TERADATA SQL.

```
set l_sql=concat('SELECT max(',l_rid_col,'), MAX(cid) INTO @c2, @c3 FROM ',p_database,'.',p_table);

SET l_rid = @c2;
SET l_cid = @c3;
```

And this update query:

```
update table_a 
set row = ifnull(l_rid, 0),
    column = ifnull(l_cid, 0) 
where databasename = p_database 
  and tablename = p_table;
```

But In Teradata I tried this way:

```
update table_a as a 
from (select max(l_rid) TR, MAX(l_cid) TCC 
      from DEVP.employees) as b
set a.row = b.TR, a.column = b.TCC 
where a.databasename = 'DEVP' 
  and a.tablename = 'employees';
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: and what happened? Did you see an error? or the query yielded different results than you expected?

Comment: Yes,   this is the error: Executed as Single statement.  Failed [3993 : HY000] Illegal usage of alias name. 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.015                          Where did I miss? @abhi

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the alias name from the LHS of the update statement.
a.colA=b.colname should be colA=b.colname

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

```
update table_a  from (select max(l_rid) TR, MAX(l_cid)  TCC from DEVP.employees )as b

set row= b.TR , column=b.TCC where databasename='DEVP' and tablename='employees';
```

ISSUE: I just removed the alias name in UPDATE. finally got it.